# Postgres with json column

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in Postgres database which has a json

`{"predict":[{"method":"A","val":1.2},{"method":"B","val":1.7}]}`

I would like to extract both val as a separate column. Is there a way I could do this from within Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres introduced [JSON types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) plus [functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) in 9.2. If your column is a JSON type you can use them to do your extraction.

Answer (score 1):

If the `json` always has the structure you indicate (i.e. a key "predict" that holds an array with two JSON objects each having a "method" and a "val" key) then the solution is simply:

```
SELECT ((my_json->'predict')->>0)->'val' AS method_a,
       ((my_json->'predict')->>1)->'val' AS method_b
FROM my_table;
```

If the structure can vary then you'd have to tell us more about it to provide you with a solution.

Comment: The column is text so I am casting it as JSON and then I keep getting this error

`ERROR: operator does not exist: json -> unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Can you please put the exact command that you use so I can see how exactly you use the cast?